# Another button on an Angular form

Tags: angular

Am building an angular app and i want to add another button on a form to do something else apart from submit and reset, but it doesn't seem to be working.
No errors. Nothing just happens

Does anyone has anything to share on this.

Angular v 4.1.1

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide more information and some code? How is it not working? Are there any generated errors?

Comment: Its not generating any errors. Nothing happens

Comment: Please add some code, mention what you have done to archive what you want, what tutorial have you followed, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` in the module first the put the `type="button"` attribute to another button it should work.